# Как проверять открыта ли страница в телефоне JS?

Tags: javascript

Я пробовал различные методы, и onBlur / onFocus но на телефоне это не работает. Как проверить, открыта ли страница у пользователя на телефоне или нет? Именно не проверка устройства, а открыта ли сама страница?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда пользователь сворачивает окно или переключается на другую вкладку, API отправляет visibilitychange событие обработчикам, что состояние страницы изменилось. Вы можете отследить это событие и выполнить какие-то действия.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

Пример:

```js
function handleVisibilityChange() {
  if (document.visibilityState === "hidden") {
    console.log('hidden');
  } else {
    console.log('visible');
  }
}

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange, false);
```

```html
Переключите вкладку или сверните браузер.
```